# Parsing Nested Bracket String in java

Tags: java, parsing, recursion, stack, brackets

I want to parse strings with (nested) brackets and values like:

```
A,(B,C),(D,(B,D),X)
```

I want the inner tuples as f.ex ArrayList, like ArrayList(B,C) or ArrayList(D,ArrayList(B,D)).

My first idea was to use a Stack, but i have problems when i have a tuple in a tuple and then after the inner tuple comes another value, like (Z,(A,B),C).

```
public static ArrayList<Object> parse(String str, ArrayList<Object> result) {
    ArrayList<Object> tmp = result;
    if (str.length() == 0) {
        return tmp;
    } else if (str.charAt(0) == '(') {
        ArrayList<Object> al = new ArrayList<Object>();
        tmp.add(al);
        str = str.substring(1, str.length());
        return parse(str, tmp);
    }else if(str.charAt(0) == ',')
    {
        str = str.substring(1,str.length());
        return parse(str,tmp);
    }
    else {
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
        al.add(""+str.charAt(0));
        tmp.add(al);

        str = str.substring(1, str.length());
        return parse(str,tmp);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Object> al = new ArrayList<Object>();
    System.out.println(parse("A,(B),(C,(D,E),F)",al));  
}
```

Output:

> [[A], [], [B], [)], [], [C], [], [D], [E], [)], [F], [)]]

Comment: You have *what* problem? 'I have a problem' is not a problem description. Please state your actual problem and exhibit the code concerned.

Comment: As a fact I do not get nested entrys, for each tuple i get a new ArrayList and no ArrayList in ArrayList when its a tuple inside a tuple..

Answer (score 0):

What problems do you get when you use a stack? You should be able to use a stack to mimic a recursive algorithm to do this. I would think of this as recursively building ArrayLists. At the base case you return the arrayList when you encounter a ')' or the end of the string, if you encounter a character add it to the list and if you encounter a '(' you should recurse. You would have to make sure the object type is abstract enough to apply to both ArrayLists and the objects your reading in.

Comment: I posted a better description @ my main post :-)